# What are the conditions like in Mercury orbit?

Tags: space, space-travel, spaceships, sunlight

In Mercury's orbit around the Sun (Solar orbit, not Mercurial orbit), what are the conditions like? What shielding or heat management would be required for a manned spacecraft? Could a spacesuited astronaut survive a space walk?

**UPDATE:**

Basic research on NASA's site gives me plenty of information about [Mercury proper](http://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/mercury/indepth) which is *hot* in the sunlight. :) NASA's [MESSENGER mission site](http://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/messenger/indepth) specifies some of the countermeasures that the MESSENGER orbiter uses. The ever-helpful Atomic Rockets site also has some helpful information about [Mercury itself](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/stellarcolony.php#id--Solar_System_Colonization--Mercury) and [heat radiators](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/basicdesign.php#id--Heat_Radiators).

Mercurial orbit also has to contend with reflected thermal radiation from Mercury's surface, but I'm specifically interested in Solar orbit (e.g. Sol-Mercury L4 or L5), where the only problem is Solar radiation.

However, I have been able to find nothing specific about the concerns of human habitation Mercury's distance from the sun. Hence this question!

Comment: Welcome to the site David, thanks for checking for info and adding that to your question.  If you have questions about the site visit the [help] or feel free to check out [chat]

Comment: @AndreiROM I hope that satisfies you that I've taken reasonable measures on my end. :) And thanks, James.

Comment: Comment deleted, and I didn't down-vote. The question is indeed much better framed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solar Probe Plus is a NASA spacecraft scheduled to launch in 2018.
It will come as close as 6 million kilometers from the Sun.

It has a carbon-carbon heat shield that has to withstand temperatures of over 1300C (2500F). Radiation exposure will also be very high (SP+ is supposed to study radiation for future manned missions to the Moon & Mars).

An astronaut would be able to survive a space walk, as long as he remains in the shade of the heat shield. He will probably be exposed to a large amount of radiation and might get radiation sickness though.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered radiation. I suppose that would require the same sort of [radiation shielding](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/radiation.php) you'd need for surviving a solar flare out in non-circumsolar space. Could our intrepid astronaut simply hide behind a water tank?

Comment: @DavidEyk Yes, water provides great radiation shielding. As long as there is enough water between you and the Sun you''ll be fine.